# Memory leak and performance of the code

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Fixing memory leaks is good thing, but I want to know apart from memory issues, does Memory leak fixes also helps to improve the performance.

Comment: It's not so much that "finding memory leaks is a good thing", but rather that *writing* memory leaks is a very *bad* thing, which basically means that you're not in control of the language or master over your design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, yes. The main reason is that with memory leaks, your program is constantly going to be getting new memory from the system which won't be in cache. If you free memory properly, you'll get that same memory back shortly, and it will already be in cache.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I buy this without data.  The other side to the argument is that about half the cost of allocation is paid in the free() call.  If you skip that, you're doing less work.  If the data is write-then-read-once (seems likely for a leak), then cache effects are irrelevant: it goes in cache once on the write, gets served from there, and then gets flushed out to spend the rest of eternity in DRAM.  The performance effect is likely to be heavily application-dependent.

Comment: I think if memory is not released properly, it results is largest memory foot print. Hence more data need to be paged between RAM and HD. This results in performance decline. so always free memory if it is not going to use again.

Comment: @AndyRoss: Cache is not irrelevant. In order to write to memory, it must be held exclusively in the L2 cache. If you allocate fresh memory, it won't be. If you re-use existing memory, it will be. These cache effects swamp the cost of a `free` in any sensible memory management implementation. (The system doesn't take into account that you don't care what the previous value was. It just knows the previous value must be invalidated, and that requires external (to the core) operations that are very expensive.)

Comment: @Andy: "rest of eternity in DRAM" - systems with virtual memory models may swap it further to disk, again affecting performance.  But, your analysis fails to consider allocations that are significantly smaller than cache and/or memory page sizes - they may be eat space because things adjacent to them are still in active use.

Comment: All I"m saying is show me the numbers, because I don't buy that argument.  And David's L2 argument is wrong.  The store forwarding hardware on Intel CPUs hides (usually) the latency involved in allocating and filling a cache line.  Writes almost never stall the pipeline except in bandwidth-limited situations (and of course if these are bandwidth-limited writes, the leak can't possibly affecting performance by definition).

Answer (score 1):

Not in a noticeable way, most likely. It might improve cache performance a little. It *might* also make a performance difference if your system is running on next to no free memory, but you will almost certainly have much larger, more noticeable performance bottlenecks in your system.

Answer (score 1):

well, memory leak actually improves performance in some way because you save time from deallocating them XD. But of course when the free memory is running low, your system will certainly experience some sort of performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

This can depend quite a bit on your code. For instance, delete is calling an object's destructor (in addition to taking time to deallocate memory) which could be time consuming, depending on the destructor's code. On the flip side, cache misses are relevant for small objects, and page faults for very large objects, so avoiding memory leaks can improve performance quite significantly too.

That said, there is very likely to be much lower hanging fruit for performance optimization than this.